# Can a SWF file be made to play wav, wma and mp4?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, format, mp4

I am putting together a website that uses a templating system. It contains a plugin that lets users upload/share music files so anyone can listen to them via the website's flash player.

It works with mp3 files only. Is there a way to make the player play other formats such as wav, wma, mp4, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the list of natively supported codecs by the Flash Player:

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/402/kb402866.html

If you need to play something not natively supported, there are external API's that will allow you to do so, just chose a Flash Sound API:

http://www.google.com.br/search?q=flash+sound+API

Comment: Good practice is to server-side re-encode everything to one common format.